# Why is my CSP header middleware not working in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-settings

I have an issue with the CSP Header and how-to parameters in the setting.py in my Django apps.
Do you know how to set up for script and style source?   and how to put the 'unsafe-inline' and 'style-src-elem' ? can someone explain how parameters works ?

setting.py

```python
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'csp.middleware.CSPMiddleware', ...]
   

    CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'none'", )
    CSP_STYLE_SRC = ("'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "fonts.googleapis.com", "'unsafe-inline'", 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com')
    CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = ("'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "ajax.googleapis.com", "www.googletagmanager.com", "www.google-analytics.com", 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net','https://code.jquery.com', "'unsafe-inline'", 'https//ajax.cloudflare.com', "'unsafe-inline'", 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlightjs-line-numbers.js/')
    CSP_IMG_SRC = ("'self'", "data:", "www.googletagmanager.com", "www.google-analytics.com")
    CSP_FONT_SRC = ("'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "fonts.gstatic.com",'https://fonts.cdnfonts.com', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com')
    CSP_CONNECT_SRC = ("'self'", )
    CSP_OBJECT_SRC = ("'none'", )
    CSP_BASE_URI = ("'none'", )
    CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ("'none'", )
    CSP_FORM_ACTION = ("'self'", )
    CSP_INCLUDE_NONCE_IN = ('script-src','script-src-elem')

    CSP_REPORT_ONLY = True
```

[Error return from google chrome localhost console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W3FQ.png)

Do you what should I do? is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an entry for the "style-src-elem" constant that these rejections are falling under. Add the rejected domains (assuming you have verified they are safe) to that grouping as a tuple

Add the following to the code:

```
CSP_STYLE_SRC_ELEM = (
    "'self'",
    "'unsafe-inline'",
    "https://fonts/cdnfonts.com",
    "https://cdn.iconmonstr.com",
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com"
)
```